# Easy way to decide if the physical door handle button or the electronics malfunctioning?

Tags: nissan, rogue, door-handle

2018 Nissan Rouge Sport - It's been snowy and freezing rain for a week or so, and the button feels "off" and only works sometimes. Any way to diagnose the physical button versus the electronics with out a "try and see"?
Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!